# Foundation 6 Zurb Template will not work offline

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, browser-sync

I installed Foundation 6 Zurb Template via the cli with no issues.
I added the missing babel install. Works fine when online. I know BrowserSync works offline but it will not.

I get Async Completion prompt after when initiating watch. I have read that adding "online:true" to BrowserSync may fix this but I dont know where to add it to in Foundation 6's gulpfile.babel.js file. New to this...

```
//Start a server with BrowserSync to preview the site in
function server(done) {
browser.init({
  server:PATHS.dist,port:PORT
});
done();
}
```

Help is appreciated! Tnx!

I get this error when trying offline:

```
[07:17:10] Requiring external module babel-register
[07:18:35] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\SMO Docs\smoProject\gulpfile.babel.js
[07:18:35] Starting 'default'...
[07:18:35] Starting 'build'...
[07:18:35] Starting 'clean'...
[07:18:35] Finished 'clean' after 50 ms
[07:18:35] Starting 'pages'...
[07:18:35] Starting 'sass'...
[07:18:35] Starting 'javascript'...
[07:18:35] Starting 'images'...
[07:18:35] Starting 'copy'...
[07:19:48] Finished 'images' after 1.22 min
[07:19:55] Finished 'pages' after 1.33 min
[07:19:55] Finished 'sass' after 1.33 min
[07:19:56] Finished 'copy' after 1.33 min
[07:20:03] Finished 'javascript' after 1.45 min
[07:20:03] Starting 'styleGuide'...
[07:20:03] Finished 'styleGuide' after 180 ms
[07:20:03] Finished 'build' after 1.47 min
[07:20:03] Starting 'server'...
[07:20:04] Finished 'server' after 1.01 s
[07:20:04] Starting 'watch'...
[07:22:18] The following tasks did not complete: default, watch
[07:22:18] Did you forget to signal async completion?
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:8000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1223:19)
    at listen (net.js:1272:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1368:5)
    at module.exports.plugin (C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\SMO Docs\smoProject\node_modules\browser-sync\lib\server\index.js:24:25)
    at Object.module.exports.startServer [as fn] (C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\SMO Docs
\smoProject\node_modules\browser-sync\lib\async.js:230:52)
    at C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\SMO Docs\smoProject\node_modules\browser-sync\lib\b
rowser-sync.js:149:14
    at iterate (C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\SMO Docs\smoProject\node_modules\browser-s
ync\lib\utils.js:268:13)
    at C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\SMO Docs\smoProject\node_modules\browser-sync\lib\u
tils.js:277:25
    at executeTask (C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\SMO Docs\smoProject\node_modules\brows
er-sync\lib\browser-sync.js:170:13)
    at Object.module.exports.setRewriteRules [as fn] (C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\SMO
Docs\smoProject\node_modules\browser-sync\lib\async.js:209:9)
    at C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\SMO Docs\smoProject\node_modules\browser-sync\lib\b
rowser-sync.js:149:14
    at iterate (C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\SMO Docs\smoProject\node_modules\browser-sync\lib\utils.js:268:13)
    at C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\SMO Docs\smoProject\node_modules\browser-sync\lib\utils.js:277:25
    at executeTask (C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\SMO Docs\smoProject\node_modules\browser-sync\lib\browser-sync.js:170:13)
 Error: foundation-zurb-template@1.0.0 start: `gulp`
Exit status 1
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
foundation-cli\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:217:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\foundation-cli\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:821:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\SMO Docs\smoProject>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if port 8000 is free and not used by any other program? Use `netstat` to list what programs are listening on what ports or try to use some other port.

```
netsat -anb
```

Comment: Thank you. The port in the gulp file was set to 8000 but it was opening on 8080 (for some reason?). I checked the netsat and nothing was on either port. I changed the port in the gulp file to 8001 and now it works.

Any idea where/how to enter the 'online:true' in Foundation 6 BrowserSync? Tnx!